# How to save spinner and reload EditText input from spinner click

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext, spinner, android-sqlite

I've create An EditText to insert my name and one to intert my surname. When i click add it must save my name into a spinner and when i click on it, i want to appear my name and my surname into edittext. I've create this code but it save it and reload only the name into EditText Name and EditText Surname..how can I do? is possible to reload also the surname only clicking the name spinner? this is my code:

```
    // Spinner element
Spinner spinner;

// Add button
Button btnAdd, btnReset;

// Input text
EditText inputLabel, surname, cf, age;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Spinner element
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    // add button
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);

    //reset Button
    btnReset =(Button) findViewById (R.id.btn_reset);

    // new label input field
    inputLabel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    surname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSurName);
    cf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCodicefiscale);
    age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAge);


    // Spinner click listener
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    // Loading spinner data from database
    loadSpinnerData();

    /**
     * Add new label button click listener
     * */
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String label = inputLabel.getText().toString();
            String label2 = surname.getText().toString();

            if (label.trim().length() > 0) {
                // database handler
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                        getApplicationContext());

                // inserting new label into database
                db.insertLabel(label);
                db.insertLabel2(label2);


                // making input filed text to blank
                inputLabel.setText("");
                surname.setText("");

                // Hiding the keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(inputLabel.getWindowToken(), 0);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(surname.getWindowToken(), 0);

                // loading spinner with newly added data
                loadSpinnerData();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter label name",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });


    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            inputLabel.setText("");
            surname.setText("");
            cf.setText("");
            age.setText("");
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Function to load the spinner data from SQLite database
 * */
private void loadSpinnerData() {
    // database handler
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    String label2 =  parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    inputLabel.setText(label);
    surname.setText(label2);
    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected: " + label,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

and this is my DatabaseHandler:

```
 // Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "spinnerExample";

// Labels table name
private static final String TABLE_LABELS = "labels";

// Labels Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_SURNAME = "surname";


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Category table create query
    String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + KEY_SURNAME + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE);


}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Inserting new lable into lables table
 * */
public void insertLabel(String label){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, label);

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_LABELS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

public void insertLabel2(String label2){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
    values2.put(KEY_SURNAME, label2);

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_LABELS, null, values2);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

/**
 * Getting all labels
 * returns list of labels
 * */
public List<String> getAllLabels(){
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning lables
    return labels;
}
```

}

Comment: to achieve current task you will need to create  an custom Adapter instead of default

Comment: We're not going to add this into your code for you... you won't learn anything if we do. What have you tried? What has worked? What hasn't? Why not? Error messages or crashes?

Comment: it function but when i insert my name and my surname, when i click on spinner it write ONLY the name on EditText Name and also on EditText Surname, for example XXX and YYY appear XXX and XXX on every ET.